# How do I find the intersection between an array of objects and a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given a Mongo collection of data of the form:

```
// 'Entities'
{ tags: [{ a: '1', b: '1' }, { a: '2', b: '3' }] }
{ tags: [{ a: '1', b: '2' }, { a: '2', b: '3' }] }
{ tags: [{ a: '4', b: '4' }, { a: '4', b: '5' }, { a: '6', b: '7' }] }
```

I'd like to find all documents whose 'tag' entry has any of the following objects:

```
[{ a: '1', b: '1' }, { a: '4', b: '4' }]
```

With the example data, this would match the first and third elements:

```
{ tags: [{ a: '1', b: '1' }, { a: '2', b: '3' }] }
{ tags: [{ a: '4', b: '4' }, { a: '4', b: '5' }, { a: '6', b: '7' }] }
```

At the moment I'm doing it with a generated query (JS):

```
entities.find({
    $or: tags.map(tag => ({
      tags: { $elemMatch: tag },
    })
})
```

But this seems very inefficient, as if the number of tags I'm searching for is large I'll be essentially running hundreds of separate queries.  Is there a better way?

Comment: maybe this way: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xpJGliuOKEr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could just use the `$in` operator instead, This should give better performance ( and cleaner code ) on large scale.

```
db.collection.find({
  approvers: {
    $in: tags
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AIc7PA-yLKN)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps nest the `$or`.

(I'm uncertain the shape of your data, but apparently `tags` is a property of `approvers`?)

```
find({
  'approvers.tags': {
    '$elemMatch': {
      $or: [
        { a: '1', b: '1' },
        { a: '4', b: '4' }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QQsFIoYUJJx)